# Session has does not work until second request

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, session-variables

I am making a simple website with Laravel and in my `PagesController` I have a function that stores an item to session and increments the `cartCount` if the item is not already stored in the session.

On my website I have a button on each item which, when clicked, sends `'item_id'` using AJAX to the website where a function `postToCart` gets called. What I want to do is: return the `item_name` when the item is successfully added.

When I click the button for the first time it tells me that the item has been added which is what I want. The problem is, when I press the button for the second time, the function `postToCart` enters the if statement again. The problem is only the second post request everything works fine after that.

```
public function postToCart(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('item_id');
    $item = Item::all()->where('item_id', '=', $id)->first();

    if (!session()->has($id))
    {
        session()->put($id, 1);
        session(['cartCount' => session('cartCount') + 1]);

        return $item->item_name;
    }
}
```

AJAX on client side:

```
function cart_click(id, url) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            'item_id': id
        },
        success: function(result){
            if (result)
            {
                alert('Item added: '.concat(result));
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Item already in cart');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, first request also enters `if` statement, second also? Is it possible first request is being ignore/errored somewhere?

Comment: Yes because I have success function implementation in ajax on client side and I am using `alert(id)` so I know when I get something returned.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` in `javascript` instead.

Comment: I could but Laravel is also supposed to work properly.

Comment: Can you post code for `success function implementation in ajax on client side`

Comment: Here you go if it helps @M Idrees 13 .

Answer (score 0):

I think there need little clarification.

First change `postToCart()` function to return some value in both cases(Success + Failure)

```
public function postToCart(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('item_id');
    $item = Item::all()->where('item_id', '=', $id)->first();

    $value = session($id, 0); 
    if ($value == 0)
    {
        session([$id => 1]);
        session(['cartCount' => session('cartCount') + 1]);

        return $item->item_name;
    }

    return "1"; 
}
```

Second in AJAX callback function, check the returned value, if there is proper message values showing clearly what happened. e.g. I put "1" as to represent already exists, otherwise I assumed it is successfully inserted.

```
success: function(result){
            if (result == "1")
            {
                alert('Item already in cart');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Item added: ' + result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of variable `result` in both cases?

Comment: In the first two requests for the same item the value of result is the name if the item and in the third request result value is "1".

Comment: I have changed session ,get/set with global session helper in `postToCart()`. Try this.

Comment: I already checked that and I checked it again now, results are the same.

Comment: But if I put `session([$id => 1]);` before the if statement, than the statement will never be executed, it seems like the first time the item does not get inserted into session.

Comment: I am not sure what happened to this. Its really strange  behavior, actually its working on my example, but I have limited code, might be possible your project have some other parts effecting this behavior. Last thing, I can guess, try changing `session()` to `$request->session()`. Sorry to say, I could not say anything more, its really confusing.

Comment: How does your routing look like?

Comment: mine is:
`Route::post('/tocart', 'PagesController@postToCart');`